# Java byte array and DataOutputStream processing

Tags: java

We are processing a byte[] as shown below (the file is POST'ed to a web server, this code is running in Glassfish) and have found that some files have a byte-order mark (BOM, a three-byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning, and we want to remove this BOM.  How would we detect and remove a BOM in this code?  Thanks.

```
  private final void serializePayloadToFile(File file, byte[] payload) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos;
    DataOutputStream dos;

    fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true); // true for append
    dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

    dos.write(payload);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
    fos.close();

    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How would we detect** [...]

There's obviously no way to tell for sure if the three bytes are three random bytes or three bytes representing a BOM.

You could check if the array starts with 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF and in that case skip them.

> [...] **and remove a BOM in this code?**

Something like this should do:

```
int off = payload.length >= 3
       && payload[0] == 0xEF
       && payload[1] == 0xBB
       && payload[2] == 0xBF ? 3 : 0

dos.write(payload, off, payload.length - off);
```

Comment: Don't forget to test `payload.length>2`

Comment: There is a way to be sure that the bytes are a BOM; if the file is encoded using UTF-8 and it starts with 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF, then those three bytes are a BOM.

Answer (score 1):

[DataOutputStream](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) has a write() method with offsets and length

```
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len);
```

So test for the byte order mark and set off (and len) appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be adding another `OutputStream` implementation between `dos` and `fos` and buffering the first few bytes there, before actually committing them to `fos`. You might or might not want to throw them away, depending on their values.

Comment: Thanks, but sounds perhaps a little too complicated...?

Comment: Yet it will work in more complicated cases than handling a byte array (like redirecting streams, etc.) :)